# matplotlib add node numbers to legend key

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, networkx

I've made a network graph with networkx and matplotlib which has 20 nodes in different shades of colour. Nodes of the same colour belong to the same category, but each have a different label. I've got the grouping sorted (although I took it out of the example below to simplify things), but I can't seem to get the node numbers to show up in the legend keys.

Here's my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_network_graph():
    nodes = ['21', '91', '60', '85', '67', '59', '29', '88', '28', '30', '76', '53', '97', '81', '64', '57', '74', '69', '35', '95']
    nodelabels = [r'Label 1', r'Label 2', r'Label 3', r'Label 4', r'Label 5', r'Label 6', r'Label 7', r'Label 8', r'Label 9', r'Label 10', r'Label 11', r'Label 12', r'Label 13', r'Label 14', r'Label 15', r'Label 16', r'Label 17', r'Label 18', r'Label 19', r'Label 20']
    nodecolours = ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#3B3B3B', '#3B3B3B', '#3B3B3B', '#4F4F4F', '#636363', '#777777', '#8B8B8B', '#8B8B8B', '#8B8B8B', '#8B8B8B', '#8B8B8B', '#9F9F9F', '#BDBDBD', '#BDBDBD', '#BDBDBD']

    nodelabeldict = {r'Label 11': ['76'],
            r'Label 1': ['21'],
            r'Label 2': ['91'],
            r'Label 3': ['60'],
            r'Label 4': ['85'],
            r'Label 5': ['67'],
            r'Label 17': ['74'],
            r'Label 18': ['69'],
            r'Label 19': ['35'],
            r'Label 20': ['95'],
            r'Label 6': ['59'],
            r'Label 7': ['29'],
            r'Label 8': ['88'],
            r'Label 12': ['53'],
            r'Label 13': ['97'],
            r'Label 14': ['81'],
            r'Label 15': ['64'],
            r'Label 16': ['57'],
            r'Label 9': ['28'],
            r'Label 10': ['30']}
    nodecolourdict = dict(zip(nodelabels, nodecolours))

    # generate the graph
    g = nx.Graph()
    for t in nodes:
        g.add_node(t)
    pos=nx.spring_layout(g)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))

    for l in nodelabels:
        llist = nodelabeldict[l]
        lcolour = nodecolourdict[l]
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,pos,nodelist=llist,
                               ax=ax,node_color=lcolour,label=l)

    nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, labels=None, font_size=10,
                  font_color='#FFFFFF', font_family='sans-serif')

    plt.axis('off')
    ax.legend(scatterpoints=1, loc=(-0.15, 0.2), shadow=True)
    plt.savefig('/tmp/network.png')
    plt.show()
```

This is what it gives me:

[image]

I would like to have the nodes' numbers in the legend too, inside the circles, just like the nodes themselves. Does anyone have any idea how to do that? I've been stuck on this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html), you can simply put your dictionary into *labels* position in nx.draw_networkx_labels, i.e.

```
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, labels=nodelabeldict, font_size=10,
              font_color='#FFFFFF', font_family='sans-serif')
```

Comment: Hi Dawid, Thanks for your reply. I think you misunderstood my question though. I'm not looking to get the labels inside the nodes, I'm looking to get the node numbers inside the nodes in the legend!

Comment: Have you tried it? Matplotlib takes the labels from plots and put them into legend, so if you modify labels they should automatically go into legend. Otherwise, might try it much later.

Comment: Hi Dawid, The numbers that are shown inside the nodes are not the labels. The labels are what you see in the legend. I want the node labels to show up in the legend next to the nodes, like what it looks like now, but then I want the numbers (I guess you'd call them the node ids) to also show up in the legend, inside the nodes, exactly the same as they are in the graph. I tried your suggestion, and I ended up with the labels in the graph. The legend stayed exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, correction: if I insert nodelabeldict as the value for labels in nx.raw_networkx_labels I get a key error, because the keys in the dictionary are labels, not node ids. So I made a dictionary the other way around, with node ids as keys and labels as values. The error disappeared, but I ended up with labels in the graph, instead of ids in the legend, like mentioned in my previous comment.